# Need solution for transpose of table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named Sample which looks like.

[image]

I want the output as following [image]

for this I have built the following Query:

```
SELECT YEAR/MONTH, 1L,3L,4L,6L,8L
    FROM (
    SELECT PANEL, LAYERCOUNT, MONTHS
    FROM Sample) up
    PIVOT (SUM(Count) FOR CountOFL IN (1L,3L,4L,6L,8L)) AS pvt
    ORDER BY YEAR/MONTH
```

But it gives error Incorrect syntax near '1'.

[image]

Comment: Do you actually need it at DB side? isn't it more a presentation matter ?

Comment: Is 1L, 3L 4l 6L 8L column names? Shouldn't they alias column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the table structures you gave, this query would return the pivoted table on the CountOFL column:

```
SELECT YEARMONTH, [1L],[3L],[4L],[6L],[8L]
FROM Sample
PIVOT (SUM(RecordCount) FOR CountOFL IN ([1L],[3L],[4L],[6L],[8L])) AS pvt
ORDER BY YEARMONTH
```

Results:

```
YEARMONTH                        1L          3L          4L          6L          8L
-------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Dec2011                          2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
Jan2011                          NULL        4           NULL        NULL        NULL
Jul2012                          2           NULL        5           NULL        NULL
Jun2011                          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        1
Jun2012                          2           NULL        NULL        1           NULL
May2011                          NULL        5           NULL        NULL        NULL
Sep2012                          NULL        1           NULL        NULL        NULL
```

So, you need to enclose the values of the PIVOTed column in square brackets.